# Geographic point created in admin Django panel is not displayed correctly located in the html

Tags: django, folium

I've created a model with postgis and rendered the templates with Folium. But when rendering the html. Geographic points appear in a geographic area that does not correspond. I've checked the srid and from what I've read they come by default at 4326 or WGS84. Can anyone help me fix this?

models.py

```
from django.contrib.gis.db import models
class Location(models.Model):name=models.CharField(max_length=250,verbose_name='nombre arbol')
punto=models.PointField()
    def str(self):
        return f"{self.punto}"`
```

views.py

```
from django.shortcuts import renderimport foliumfrom .models import *
def home(request):
    locations=Location.objects.all()initialMap=folium.Map(location=[-33.56919516402464, -70.81542789027874], zoom_start=18)
    for location in locations:    
        folium.Marker(location.punto ,popup='Arbol'+ location.punto ).add_to(initialMap)
    context={'map':initialMap._repr_html_(),'locations':locations}
    return render(request, 'survey/home.html',context)
```

admin.py

```
from django.contrib import adminfrom .models import * 
admin.site.register(Location)
```

[error points](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JVLNl.png)

[This is where the dots should appear](https://i.stack.imgur.com/k8V8N.png)

I need to know what I need to set so that the points appear where they correspond geographically where I created them (I created them from the Django admin panel)

[Point Creation from admnin panel](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tdsSQ.png)

here is the libs installed on my venv

asgiref==3.7.2

branca==0.6.0

certifi==2023.7.22

charset-normalizer==3.3.1

Django==4.2.6

folium==0.14.0

GDAL @ file:///-/Downloads/GDAL-3.4.3-cp311-cp311-win_amd64.whl#sha256=f78861fb5115d5c2f8cf3c52a492ff548da9e1256dc84088947379f90e77e5b6

idna==3.4

Jinja2==3.1.2

MarkupSafe==2.1.3

numpy==1.26.1

psycopg2==2.9.9

requests==2.31.0

sqlparse==0.4.4

tzdata==2023.3

urllib3==2.0.7

I would appreciate your help, thank you very much for your time.